# Error while geting html code

Tags: html, c++, qt

I'm trying to get html code using QNetworkAccessManager, but it doesn't work. Result of reply in my program is site, but i need html. How can i convert it?

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *pwgt): QWidget(pwgt)
{
   field = new QTextEdit(this);
   QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com")));
   QEventLoop loop;
   connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
   loop.exec();
   QString text = reply->read();
   field->setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt documentation :

> void QTextEdit::setText(const QString & text) [slot]
>
> Sets the text edit's text. The text can be plain text or HTML and the
> text edit will try to guess the right format.
>
> Use setHtml() or setPlainText() directly to avoid text edit's
> guessing.

You can use `QTextEdit::setPlainText` which sets the text editor's contents as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not try to make asynchronous code synchronous...

The problem could be that you're reading the content of the reply before the request could be finished. Connect the `finished()` signal with a slot (of your class) at try to read the data there (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)

Try also using `readAll()` for the QNetworkReply